# Magento 2 - Ui Component Form: Change input name

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform, uicomponent

I use Ui Component to build backend form.

This field when rendered has attribute **[name=template_id]**. But I want this field to have attribute **[name=id]**. Please help me to do this.

If there is any information needed to solve this problem, please ask me. I will provide it later.

Thanks a lot.

```
    <field name="id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">template_id</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">template</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change

```
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">template_id</item>
```

to

```
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">id</item>
```